# Remove <span> and </span> in Text using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the text available inside the `<a>` elements. I have used the innerHTML to retrieve that inner text, but in few `<a>` elements the inner Text is placed inside the `<span>` elements.

While retrieving the text value am getting it as `<span>sample text</span>` as the output string. Can anyone help me to remove the `<span></span>` in the output string using RegEx so that i can only have `sample text` in my output string.

```
<a href="#"><span>Sample Text</span></a>
```

Note: I am not using any Javascript Libraries in the page.

Comment: [HTML tags lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, the song of re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal man from the final ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the omes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Leaving the obligatory link for [why you shouldn't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can include jQuery, you can use - `$("a").text()` without using any regex.

And with pure JavScript -

```
/* elem you can get in many ways, by id, by tagname or by class etc.
   I am using tagName for your specific case
*/
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0],

/* use innerText or textContent, whichever is available in browser */     
var content = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;
```

Comment: You might want to point out that the OP needs to include the jQuery library, because the question is only tagged Javascript

Comment: Actually, the OP specifically says they're **not** using any libraries.

Comment: Downvote :(, During I was fixing it. I should have got some time to breath.

Comment: Will it be having Cross Browser Compatibility issues.. as far as i know textContent will not work in IE8?

Comment: @codeMad `elem.innerText || elem.textContent` is taking care of it.

Comment: Jeezes, you even stole my variable names !

Comment: @adeneo sorry, I was lazy to type :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` or `textContent` (depending on the browser) gets the elements text without the span tags :

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
    text = ('innerText' in elem)? 'innerText' : 'textContent';

var content = elem[text];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8cPt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll to find all `<a>` tags with `<span>` children and take the text as necessary:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a > span");
for(var e in elems) {
  var element = elems[e];
  var aTag = element.parentNode;
  if(aTag.innerText) aTag.innerText = element.innerText;
  else aTag.textContent = element.textContent;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/9SLPp/) is a jsFiddle to demonstrate the above.

To clarify, `document.querySelectorAll` is only natively supported on IE8+ ([and most other modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)) but polyfills are available.